# The process cannot access the file Log.txt

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, streamwriter

I have a Windows Service which reads information from an IoT Hub, and it logs everything as it happens, however I am getting this error
The process cannot acess the file.

My best guess, as some of things are async, is that another thread is trying to write to the log, while one is writing to it.

Service1cs

```
 public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        EventProcessorHost _eventProcessorHost;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {          
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); //para hacer debugger
                WriteMessageLog($"Inicio lectura mensajes : {DateTime.Now}",DateTime.Now);
                string storageConnectionString =
                    $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={Configuracion.StorageAccountName};AccountKey={Configuracion.StorageAccountKey}";
                string _guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string eventProcessorHostName = _guid;
                _eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
                                                                eventProcessorHostName,
                                                                Configuracion.EventHubName,
                                                                EventHubConsumerGroup.DefaultGroupName,
                                                                Configuracion.EventHubConnectionString,
                                                                storageConnectionString);
                var options = new EventProcessorOptions
                {
                    MaxBatchSize = 100,
                    PrefetchCount = 10,
                    ReceiveTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
                    InitialOffsetProvider = (name) => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
                };


                options.ExceptionReceived += OnExceptionReceived;
                _eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>(options).Wait();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteMessageLog($"Error WindowsService; {ex.Message}", DateTime.Now);
                WriteMessageLog($"Error WindowsService; {ex.StackTrace}",DateTime.Now);
                //throw ex;
            }

        }



        public void WriteMessageLog(string msg, DateTime now)
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
                var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\..\LogTempSense.txt"));

                if (!File.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(newPath))
                    {
                        string logLine = $"{GetTimeStamp(now):G}   Mensaje: {msg}.";
                        sw.WriteLine(logLine);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(newPath, true))
                    {
                        string logLine = $"{GetTimeStamp(now):G}   Mensaje: {msg}.";
                        file.WriteLine(logLine);
                        file.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteMessageLog($"Error escribiendo log; {e.Message}",DateTime.Now);
            }
        }

        private string GetTimeStamp(DateTime now)
        {
            return string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                 "{0:D2}/{1:D2}/{2:D2} {3:D2}:{4:D2}:{5:D2}:{6:D3}",
                                 now.Day,
                                 now.Month,
                                 now.Year,
                                 now.Hour,
                                 now.Minute,
                                 now.Second,
                                 now.Millisecond);
        }

        public void OnExceptionReceived(object sender, ExceptionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            WriteMessageLog(String.Format("Error Event Hub exception received; {0} ", args.Exception.Message), DateTime.Now);
        }

        public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _eventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync().Wait();
            WriteMessageLog($"Fin lectura mensajes : {DateTime.Now}", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

**SimpleEventProcesor.cs**

```
class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
    {
        Service1 Service1 = new Service1();
        Stopwatch _checkpointStopWatch;

        async Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
        {
            Service1.WriteMessageLog(string.Format("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason:'{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason),DateTime.Now);
            if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
            {
                await context.CheckpointAsync();
            }
        }

        Task IEventProcessor.OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
        {
            Service1.WriteMessageLog(string.Format("SimpleEventProcessor initialized. Partition:'{0}',offset:'{1}'", context.Lease.PartitionId, context.Lease.Offset),DateTime.Now);
            _checkpointStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            _checkpointStopWatch.Start();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);               

        }

        public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
        {
            int messageCount = 0;
            foreach (EventData eventData in messages)
            {
                messageCount++;
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
                var deviceId = int.Parse(o["deviceId"].ToString()); 
                var value = decimal.Parse(o["valor"].ToString());
                var date = DateTime.Parse( o["fecha"].ToString());
                using (ActiveSenseContext db = new ActiveSenseContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TempsenseConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                         var dispositivo = db.Dispositivos
                            .Where(p => p.DispositivoID == deviceId);

                        if (dispositivo.ToList().Count > 0)
                        {
                            Medida medida = new Medida()
                            {
                                DispositivoID = dispositivo.FirstOrDefault().DispositivoID,
                                Valor = value,
                                FechaHora = date,
                            };
                            Service1.WriteMessageLog(
                                $"Message received. Partition:{context.Lease.PartitionId}, Data:{data}{eventData.EnqueuedTimeUtc}",DateTime.Now);

                            if (bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AddDataInAppEngine"].ToString()))
                            {
                                using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TempsenseConnection2"].ConnectionString))
                                {
                                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                                    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TempSense_AppEngine_Medidas (Valor, FechaHora, DispositivoI) VALUES(" + medida.Valor + "," + medida.FechaHora + "," + medida.DispositivoID + ")";
                                    //cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TempSense_AppEngine_Dispositivo (DispositivoI) VALUES(" + medida.DispositivoID + ")";
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }

                                db.Medidas.Add(medida);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                db.Medidas.Add(medida);
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Service1.WriteMessageLog(
                                $"Device Key not found in database:{o["deviceKey"]}, Message:{o}",DateTime.Now);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Service1.WriteMessageLog($"Mensaje tuvo error:{ex.Message},{data}",DateTime.Now);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (messageCount > Configuracion.TamanoLoteMensajes)

                context.CheckpointAsync();
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
 en System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   en System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   en System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   en ActiveSense.Tempsense.WindowsService.Utilities.WriteMessageLog(String msg, DateTime now) en C:\Desarrollo Software\2. Sprint Execution\3. Construcción\Dev2\ActiveSense.Tempsense.web\ActiveSense.Tempsense.WindowsService\Utilities.cs:línea 32
```

Comment: At what point are you getting the error?

Comment: So you should use lock keyword to make sure just one process at time accessing your file. Maybe a Message-Queue would be better because massiv locks make async useless.

Comment: where exactly should I use lock?

Comment: at    file.WriteLine(logLine);

Comment: actually the error happens on this line:   using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(newPath, true))
                      However, I tried the LOCK on the entire methd and it  didnt work

Comment: Share exact error message with stacktrace

Comment: just added the stacktrace, I refactored the writemessagelog to a static class called Utilities for better reading